# sprite kit crash'Invalid size specified: {0, 0}'

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit, xcode5.1

Currently trying to make a lite version of my game, but i keep getting the following error,"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid size specified', reason: 'Invalid size specified: {0, 0}'"

I know the problem lies somewhere in here:

```
-(void)liteOver {

int liteScore = score;

if (liteScore >= 10) {

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setInteger:score forKey:@"playerScore"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    int highScore = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"High Score"] integerValue];
    if (highScore){
        if (highScore < score){
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:score] forKey:@"High Score"];
        }
    }
    else{
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:score] forKey:@"High Score"];
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:0.75];
    MGLCreateGameOverScene *scene = [MGLCreateGameOverScene sceneWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
    [self.view presentScene:scene transition:reveal];

    liteScore = 0;

}

[self performSelector:@selector(liteOver) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
}
```

Any help on what "invalid size specified" means would be a big help.

Comment: check self.vie.bounds.size - self.view may be nil

Comment: @LearnCocos2d changing it to self.size did fix the problems, thanks